# ubuntu (setup using chef) - issues updating packages on the system (e.g php, rubygems plus others)

Tags: ubuntu, updates, repository, rubygems, chef

I would really appreciate some help with this as I've been trawling google for days now and coming up empty.

Background, I'm using chef-solo/vagrant to build a development webserver, I have used a raring (ubuntu 13.04) base box which comes with ruby and chef installed.

I have installed a full lamp stack and everything is working great. But there are a couple of ruby gems I need to install which require version 1.9.x, 1.8.x is installed. So i tried to update rubygems and it returned with a success message. However the system still reports version 1.8.x.

There is a similar situation with php, I previously asked this question https://superuser.com/questions/607629/ubuntu-12-04-cli-using-correct-php-version-apache-is-not regarding issues upgrading php on a ubuntu 12.04 base box. With the new basebox I can now get php to version 5.4.9 but cannot get it to run the latest stable release without installing from source - in which case I have the same issue discussed in the previous question.

There are similar issues updating other programs and packages. So what is happening here? Are all software updates locked due to it being an LTS release.

I dont think this is a chef issue as when I ssh into the box I get the same results, I have a feeling it's something to do with the base boxes. Any help diagnosing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Package: ruby1.9.1 (1.9.3.194-8.1ubuntu1) from the URL at:
[packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ruby1.9.1]

I usually consult [packages.ubuntu.com/] then select the relevant release, in this case, [packages.ubuntu.com/raring/] and visit the bottom of the web page to get the link for All Packages at [packages.ubuntu.com/raring/allpackages]

Then after the webpage completes loading (take a couple of minutes), I searched for ruby and found:

rubygems1.9.1
    virtual package provided by ruby1.9.1

which linked to ruby 1.9.1 at [packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby1.9.1]
which in turn linked to ruby1.9.1 (1.9.3.194-8.1ubuntu1) at its webpage:
[packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ruby1.9.1]